# How does one debug NextJS React apps with WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, debugging, webstorm, next.js

I'm trying to use the WebStorm IDE debugger to debug a NextJS React app.  I tried to use a JavaScript configuration, but that didn't seem to work -- neither when I used a Node config.

What's the correct procedure for debugging NextJS React apps with WebStorm?

Answer (score 42):

The following steps work for me:

- start the app with next (`npm run dev` or whatever your start script looks like)
- add breakpoints, create **JavaScript Debug** run configuration, specify `http://localhost:3000` URL
- debug

If you like to debug the code that is executed on the server side, I'd suggest using the **Node.js** run configuration with `node_modules\next\dist\bin\next` specified as **Javascript file:**

[image]

You can then debug both **Node.js** and **Javascript Debug** run configurations to get both server-side and client-side code debugged.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work with simple projects, but in the project I'm working on the "pages" directory is not in the project root, but some levels down, '/src/common/pages' and when I launch the debugger I get the error "Debugger attached.
> Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root".  I am trying at the moment to debug a node module at the moment, so I don't want to set the project root to the 'common' directory...

Comment: In my case, there was no `.next/dist/bin/next` file, regardless of production or dev deploy. Clicking the debug mode on `package.json`'s `next` script seemed to work for the server side debug.

Comment: I confirmed that `next` command in package.json scripts just starts debugging with Node 12.14.1, while v13.3.0 couldn't connect the debugger.

Comment: I can confirm that this works on NextJs version 14.1.0. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 36):

I found that clicking the play button next to `dev` in `package.json` and selecting the debug option worked for debugging my API served by Next.js.

[image]

This automatically creates the run configuration. Breakpoints are flakey though, I think because I'm using TypeScript. I need to edit the file after adding the breakpoint for them to work.

Comment: It doesn't stop at the breakpoints me even if I edit the file.  Although I am using PyCharm pro version, not WebStorm.

Comment: same for me using WebStorm, some of the breakpoints seems to be working, but not all of them.

Comment: If only some of your breakpoints are working, it could be that you're only capturing server-side or client-side breakpoints. Remember NextJS can run the same code server-side (SSR) or client-side

Comment: @Nils Works for me on the server but don't detect breakpoints in Browser! how can fix it?

Comment: I think we have to add the breakpoint on the generated .js file... it seems to work there...

Comment: Is this documented by JetBrains? I spent a good deal of time poring over their docs and there's no mention of this here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/react.html#react_running_and_debugging_debug Granted, that's for PyCharm, but I believe the feature sets and docs are similar if not identical

Answer (score 7):

for the Frontend of next.js:

Start debugging your app right from the Run tool window below ↓. Just hold Ctrl+Shift / ⌘⇧ and click the URL address where the application is running. WebStorm launches the auto generated Debug Application run/debug configuration, the browser opens at http://localhost:3000/, and the Debug tool window appears showing you the call stack and variables.

[image]

https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-react-apps/#launch_a_debugging_session

Comment: he say Next js You say Create React App?!! do not useful for Next js.

Comment: @MohmmadEbrahimiAval No, I'm actually demonstrating how to do this in a NEXT.JS app. and since it's identical to react I also provided further instructions...

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using both WebStorm and Rider, and in both of these IDEs, breakpoints randomly stop being hit after some time.

As a workaround, I just stop and rerun the process, which makes breakpoints hit again.

[image]
[image]

If there is a better way to cope with this weird problem, I'd love to hear it in the comments.